# How do I cancel numericupdown_valuechanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code. I am trying to create DateTime using numeric up-down. I get exception

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '1/3/0001 12:00:00 AM'
>   is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and
>   'MaxDate'.
>       Parameter name: Value'

I tried using the validating event for numeric-up-down, but then it is not firing.

```
 public DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime referencetime = default(DateTime))
    {
        if (referencetime == default(DateTime)) referencetime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime returntime = referencetime;
        try
        {
            returntime = new DateTime(
                !Year.IsRelative ? Year.Value : referencetime.Year,
                !Month.IsRelative ? Month.Value : referencetime.Month,
                !Day.IsRelative ? Day.Value : referencetime.Day,
                !Hour.IsRelative ? Hour.Value : referencetime.Hour,
                !Minute.IsRelative ? Minute.Value : referencetime.Minute,
                !Second.IsRelative ? Second.Value : referencetime.Second
            );

            if (Year.IsRelative)
                returntime = returntime.AddYears(Year.Value);
            if (Month.IsRelative)
                returntime = returntime.AddMonths(Month.Value);
            if (Day.IsRelative)
                returntime = returntime.AddDays(Day.Value);
            if (Hour.IsRelative)
                returntime = returntime.AddHours(Hour.Value);
            if (Minute.IsRelative)
                returntime = returntime.AddMinutes(Minute.Value);
            if (Second.IsRelative)
                returntime = returntime.AddSeconds(Second.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
```

[DateTime.cs Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8TFR.png)

I want to cancel the value_changed event for `outofRange` exception results. How do I do it?

Comment: is your `try catch` is working on that particular error?

Comment: Wow, that building concept is quite clever! Are you really sure your controls are actually just accepting numbers? Make sure the "candidate" values will be valid ones. Give a try to DateTime.TryParse

Comment: It is an exception that is generated by DateTimePicker, possibly MonthCalendar.  We can't see it.  Minimum allowed date for those controls is 1/1/1753, the day that England switched from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar.  Earlier dates are pretty meaningless.  Do strongly strive for a UI design that does not allow the user to select an invalid date or a weirdo mix of current and custom date/time parts.  Since you seem to use DateTimePicker anyway, you might as well use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Mininum** and **Maximum** properties of **NumericUpDown** control, on properties window as well as programmatically to avoid unwanted range.

Also you can use `Validating` event to cancel or set any other value to the control. I used this event to convert decimal value to int (user can enter any decimal value within the range). See the complete working project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/evay8qldycnojor/WindowsFormsApp1.zip?dl=0).

Please let me know if you have further query on this.

Comment: Thanks. I handled it in catch block.